# Is there a way to distinguish between custom remote methods and standard remote methods?

Tags: loopbackjs

In lb v3 is there a way to distinguish between standard remote methods and custom remote methods?

For e.g. I create a remote method as follows:

```js
Customer.order_status = function(orderId, cb) {
// ...
};

Customer.remoteMethod(
// remote method definition
);
```

Now in suppose a `afterRemote()` or `beforeRemote()` call (defined in a mixin for e.g.), is there anyway to figure out if this is a custom remote method call or a standard remote method call (like `find`, `findById`, etc)?

```
TargetModel.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, next) {
let methodString = ctx.methodString;

}
```

The method string for a `order_status` call would be something like `Customer.order_status`, and, say, if it was defined as a non-static method, it would have been `Customer.prototype.order_status`. Now, I can test for the truthfullness in the model constructor to determine if it is a valid method.

For e.g.

```js
!!TargetModel[remoteMethodname] // true if it is a valid static method.
```

However, I don't have the information yet. I don't know if it is a static method defined as a custom remote method.

Further, if we have defined a scope on the model it further complicates things. I cannot distinguish between a scope remote call or a standard remote call based on the above approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

We don't distinguish between built-in and user-provided remote methods in LoopBack. However, it is possible to add a flag to remoting metadata for custom methods defined in your project.

For example:

```js
Customer.remoteMethod('foo', {
  // your custom flag
  custom: true,

  // standard remoting metadata
  accepts: [/*...*/],
  returns: [/*...*/],
  // etc.
});
```

Then in your remoting hook, you can access remoting metadata via `ctx.method.{field}`, for example:

```js
TargetModel.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, next) {
  const isCustom = ctx.method.custom;
  // ...
});
```